# C: Variable turns to 0 simply calling getline inside for loop

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, static, getline

In the following code (simplified version of my source code) the variable `lv` which is initialized to `1` right when declared, mysteriously turns to 0 when `getline` is called inside the `for` loop. You may notice it from the `printf` if you enter anything but `"cl"`, or via gdb. The variable changes value right after the `getline` call.
The most strange thing is that when entering `"cl"` when prompted, you may see via gdb that the value of `lv` turns to `0` right after `getline`, then it is correctly set to `3` in the `if` statement and then is preserved for subsequent loops, whatever you enter.

Moreover if you change the declaration to `static int lv = 1;` then the expected behaviour occours (`lv` stays to `1` until 'manually' changed).

Someone can please tell me what the hell is going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ( void ) {
  char* line=NULL;
  int len;
  int lv = 1;
  for(;;) { 
    printf("Level: %d\n", lv);

    getline(&line, (size_t*)&len, stdin);

    if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n') {
      line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    if (strcmp(line, "cl")==0) {
      lv = 3;
    } else if (strcmp(line, "hi")==0) {
      printf("Hello World!\n");
    } else if (strcmp(line, "quit")==0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: what platform is this?

Comment: Another nice example of why one shall not blindly "cast away" compiler warnings/error.

Comment: `size_t` is `typedef`ed as `long` and is a type guaranteed to hold any array index. I doubt if that really shed in any light *directly*. Declare `len` as `size_t` or `long` and it should work.

Comment: As others have said:  `size_t` is `size_t`.  It's **not** an `int`.  It's **not** a `long`.  It **is** `size_t`.

Comment: What is getline? Is this C or C++? If it is C++, how do you manage to compile it? Compile your code with a conforming compiler!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it is linux, compiled with gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2

Comment: @Lundin it is C, not C++

Comment: @alk the compiler does not raise any error or warning, maybe the default is too silent.

Comment: @Earendil There is no function called getline in C, nor is the compiler allowed to declare one inside the standard libraries. So this code will not compile on any conforming compiler.

Comment: @Lundin I'm actually not sure if gcc is a conforming compiler, but I'm very inclined to think so. `getline` is declared in stdio.h, for reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Comment: @Earendil: So where does this `(size_t*)` come from? For which reason had it been put there, but to silence the compiler?

Comment: @Earendil Most people apparently don't know how to use gcc as a strictly conforming C compiler. It comes as a non-standard nonsense compiler out of the box. Call it with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Then it correctly gives the error "implicit declaration of function getline". When compiled as standard C, the function was removed, because a conforming compiler is not allowed to dump their crap inside the standard libraries. And as you can read from that link "So the GNU C Library provides the nonstandard getline function...".

Comment: @Lundin You are right, I didn't notice it. Anyway I can't understand why a function such `getline` is not standardized, given the deficiencies of the standard `gets` and `fgets`. Obviously I'm not nearly expert enough to understand thoroughly these io-interactions and thus the decisions made by the standard.

Comment: @alk actually I didn't get your first comment, my fault :). Anyway that part of code is taken verbatim from the slides of the professor of Operating Systems at my university, so the real lesson here is don't trust casts, and your prof either ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A logical explanation would be that on your platform `size_t` is bigger than `int`.

If that's the case, your code has UB, and the `lv` variable gets overwritten when `getline` updates `len`.

Simply declare `len` as `size_t`.

Comment: I think you got it right. Is it then that defining `lv` static another memory region is selected so no overwrite occurs?

Answer (score 0):

one problem, which would be listed by the compiler, is that getline() (on linux) is not prototyped in stdio.h unless written like so:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
```

there are also two other warnings raised by the compiler about the unused parameters 'argc' and 'argv'  suggest changing the main function declaration to:

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: My compiler (also linux) finds `getline` without any problem. The arguments of `main` are a residue: I cut off the parts of code where `argc` and `argv` were used, but forgot to delete them in `main()`, I'm editing the question for consistency.